# Extract Year/Month Value from DateTime Column in U-SQL

Tags: datetime, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I have created a u-sql script which uses a year value from a column and using that value in a **WHERE** condition.

> @res = SELECT * FROM @result WHERE (CreatedDate).ToString("yyyy") == 2000; OUTPUT @res TO "E:/system/2000.csv" USING Outputters.Csv();

(CreatedDate).ToString("yyyy") is not working as it is showing following error,

```
 DESCRIPTION
 C# compiler reported that this expression is not valid C#.
```

Answer (score 1):

We have to Replace CreatedDate.Year with **CreatedDate.Value.Year**

For Example,

```
@res = SELECT * FROM @result WHERE CreatedDate.Value.Year == 2000; OUTPUT @res TO "E:/system/2000.csv" USING Outputters.Csv();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a string on the left and an int on the right.  Consider:
1) .... == "2000", or
2) CreatedDate.Year == ....

Comment: CreatedDate.Year is showing the same error,  C# compiler reported that this expression is not valid C#.